# how to use variable to display date in datepicker HTML?

Tags: laravel, datepicker

I want to make edit operation using variable. I am trying fetch date into html `bootstrap datepicker`.
Herein my code where should put my fetching variable?

```html
        <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
            {!! Form::label('tradedate', 'Traded date:') !!}
            <div class=" input-append date form_datetime" id="datetimepicker" data-date="{{date('Y-m-d H:i:s')}}" data-date-format="dd MM yyyy - HH:ii p" data-link-field="dtp_input1">
                <input size="16" type="text"  onfocusout = 'all_function()' value="" readonly class="form-control">
                <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-remove"></i></span>
                <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" id="dtp_input1" value="" name="tradedate" />
        </div>
```

```
    public function edit($id)
{

    $trade = Trade::findOrFail($id);

    return view('member.add-single-trade.edit', compact('trade'));
}
```

`$trade` has date which i want to edit it for datepicker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have passed `compact('trade')` into your blade template you can simply use `{{ $trade }}` in your template. I am not sure what you're date column is called so I use the `created_at` timestamp as an example.

```
{{ $trade->created_at }}
```

So modifying your code to what I think you are wanting:

```html
        <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
            {!! Form::label('tradedate', 'Traded date:') !!}
            <div class=" input-append date form_datetime" id="datetimepicker" data-date="{{date('Y-m-d H:i:s')}}" data-date-format="dd MM yyyy - HH:ii p" data-link-field="dtp_input1">
                <input size="16" type="text"  onfocusout = 'all_function()' value="{{ $trade->created_at }}" readonly class="form-control">
                <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-remove"></i></span>
                <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" id="dtp_input1" value="" name="tradedate" />
        </div>
```

Comment: Not a problem @KinnariPrajapati, enjoy building your app!